# Assign User within range of selection

Tags: interaction-design, time, sliders, range

There is a horizontal timeline, divided by seven and for each divided again by - whereas the main division is for days, the second one is for AM/PM.

Now you can select range of days - defining an over-time-event; selection is defined by dragging the sides of the rectangle: the active area.

Now by selecting a maximum range of 5 day/s, a profile ( which is going to be a Human Being going to the 'event') has to be defined providing: telephone number, name and surname, 'date from' and 'date to' with 'time from' and 'time to';

Now the profile availability can cover the whole 'over-time-event' or either small lapse of time - also by providing multiple contacts.

How would you ***show*** the 'profile assignment'? Also ***what*** would you use to input the data?

---

*My concern on top of it is to have a simple selection without further thinking.
By showing the horizontal timeline with a progressive 'drag-selection' usr mental model is progressing from present to past/future events.*

---

Comment: Can you rephrase "I am either thinking to dig over input texts or either having something easy to have. What do you think about it?" - I don't quite follow.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Can you provide a diagram or pictures to show us what you're talking about?

Comment: Infiniteloop, I tried to rephrase your question. Let me know if this is what you're trying to say.

Comment: Any particular reason why you chose slider for this feature? Also, can you post the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user pulls the slider beyond the acceptable range, invoke a popup that offers the inputs and date pickers they need need. A technically easier implementation would be to have the same inputs in a modal dialog, but having it appear over the slider would be preferable.

An example of how you might make this even smoother is to make the assumption that most users will set their start date first and then drag the slider to the right (you could test this with some observation) In this case you could prefill the "From:" field in the popup with the start date, saving the user one interaction.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft7krg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I Am now looking to visualise this data within a clear interface for new millennial users.

Like the tooltip box. Surely useful for whom might also have a look in this post.

All the best
Thank you